# How can I navigate back to the previous page in the OnLaunched() event?

Tags: c#, windows-8, lifecycle, windows-store-apps, terminate

If my app is terminated by Windows (e.g, if it has been suspended, but then Windows needs to free up memory so it preempts my app), when it is restarted, the OnLaunched() event occurs and I can test whether it was Terminated (or the user simply closed it):

```
    . . .
        if ((args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated) ||
            (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser))
        {
        }
    . . .
```

If terminated, I'd like to resume at the previous location/page, rather than at the initial page (if different). How can I do this? Pseudocode might be:

```
if (CurrentPage != LastSavedPage)
{
    CurrentPage = LastSavedPage;
    // or: Frame.Navigate(typeof(LastSavedPage)
}
```

### UPDATE

So this is my take on what I should do, but I still "have a doubt about it" (see comment and code following it)

```
// OnNavigateTo in each page:
Settings.Values["CurrentPageType"] = this.GetType();
Settings.Values["CurrentPageParam"] = args.Parameter; 
//Will the line directly above work even if args.Parameter is empty, or must I do something like:
if (null != args.Parameters)
{
     Settings.Values["CurrentPageParam"] = args.Parameter; 
}

//OnLaunched in app.xaml.cs
                if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    if ((localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageType")) &&
                        (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageParam")))
                    {
                        rootFrame.Navigate((Type)localSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"],
                                                                     localSettings.Values["CurrentPageParam"]);
                    }
                }
```

### UPDATE 2

I get an exception with this code:

```
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"] = this.GetType();
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["CurrentPageParam"] = args.Parameter;
```

*An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store
Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

If I append ".ToString()" to the call to GetType(), it doesn't blow up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! When you override OnNavigatedTo you need to persist two things:

1) The type of the current class, something like:

```
Settings.Values["CurrentPageType"] = this.GetType();
```

2) The params passed to the current page, something like:

```
Settings.Values["CurrentPageParams"] = e.Parameters;
```

The first caveat is that your parameters must be serializeable. That's up to you.

The second consideration is if your applications relies on the backstack for navigation. if so, then you will need to persist more than just the current page's type, but the breadcrumb behind it. That's up to you, too.

Then it's just something like:

```
Frame.Navigate(
    (Type)Settings.Values["CurrentPageType"], 
    Settings.Values["CurrentPageParams"]);
```

Please check for nulls and stuff like that. But, ion a nutshell, that's how.

Comment: By "checking for nulls..." I reckon you mean those cases where the CurrentPageParams will be empty because not all of my pages are sent params (some are, some aren't). Of course, in each page I'll know whether it took a param or not; if not, what should I assign the CurrentPageParams key?

Comment: The GetType() throws an exception. I've added details above in Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the type of last page your app was on when it was suspended, and after the new start navigate to the proper page in your App class. This should not be so hard to implement.

Comment: Martin, Suchan awesome fellow.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers (skip to bottom for TL;DR version)...

If you're using the C#/XAML Grid or Split templates or adding anything but a Blank Page to a project, you'll be pulling in the [SuspensionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986968.aspx) 'helper' class which sets up most of the plumbing for you.

Each of the non-blank pages extends `LayoutAwarePage`, which provides a `OnNavigatedTo` implementation like Jerry mentioned.  In each page though, you only need to fill in the body of a `LoadState` and `SaveState` method - putting whatever you want to persist into a `pageState` parameter. **And it persists the page the user was on without you doing anything** - you just need to add any additional data you want to save (and restore).

The `pageState` gets stored in a file within your application directory (versus using Settings). If you go manual with Settings you do have to make sure everything is a Windows Runtime Type (primarily just simple types and arrays), but with pageState it can serialize objects as well.

> Check out the sample walkthrough [Manage
>   app lifecycle and state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986968.aspx) for some real code and further
>   explanation.

Comment: I did start with a "Blank" project, so don't have that SuspensionManager/LayoutAwarePage stuff. I tried that, too, but decided to go "minimal"...we'll see - maybe I'll eventually change back...

Comment: if you add a 'non-blank' page to the existing infrastructure, you'll get most of what you need added for you - the walkthrough actually does it this way IIRC.  It may be a matter of simply changing your existing pages to inherit from LayoutAwarePage instead of Page.